# Multithreading in openCV4Android

Tags: android, multithreading, opencv, image-processing

I want to process images captured from Android camera in real-time.
I want to process all the 29-30 frames(per sec) which I can capture from CAM (processing need not be real time). 
However when I process the frames one by one in a single thread, my effective frame rate becomes 3-5 as the algorithm involves some looping and I miss out lot of frames.

Can I go for multithreading, say one thread just keep storing the image in an array, (storing 10 image sequence will be enough) and one thread extract images from the array one by one  and process it!!! I dont want to display the image in real time....just i want real time image capture. Will it help?

Is it supported???